# convert work seconds into weeks, daysm, hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, jira-rest-api

I am using the jira rest api to get an issue. The issues estimated time is returned as a number of seconds - but based on 5-days a week, 8 hour a day.

so, for example, an estimated time of `1d` is being returned as 28800 seconds

I have got this code that does what I want, but it smells and I was wondering if there were a better function to do what I want

```
 let es = 246180; // time (number of *work* seconds) is "1w 3d 4h 23m"
 let sInMin = 60;
 let sInHour = (60 * 60);
 let sInDay  = (sInHour * 8);
 let sInWeek = (sInDay * 5);

 let w = Math.trunc(es / sInWeek);
 let d = Math.trunc((es - (w * sInWeek)) / sInDay);
 let h = Math.trunc((es - (w * sInWeek) - (d * sInDay)) / sInHour);
 let m = Math.trunc((es - (w * sInWeek) - (d * sInDay) - (h * sInHour)) / sInMin);

 console.log(w,d,h,m)  // 1 3 4 23
```

if I add `moment` and `moment-duration-format` to the mix, I can then do

```
moment.duration({w,d,h,m}).format("w[w] d[d] h[h] m[m]")
```

to get to the magical `1w 3d 4h 23m` string

How can I improve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The JIRA REST API already gives you the field you are trying to compute.

From the sample response in their docs [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getIssue):

```json
"timetracking": {
    "originalEstimate": "10m",
    "remainingEstimate": "3m",
    "timeSpent": "6m",
    "originalEstimateSeconds": 600,
    "remainingEstimateSeconds": 200,
    "timeSpentSeconds": 400
    }
```

You're grabbing the `originalEstimateSeconds` field and trying to do math to get the string, but the string is already made fore you in the `originalEstimate` field.  No need to calculate it.

Comment: well, that kinda sucks , because I have to use the search api to get the issue in question (searching by the externalId) and *that* api doesn't seem to return timetracking , just the actual seconds value.

The jira api is so *bloody* inconsistent, it drives me mad ;(

Thanks for the headsup

Comment: Which specific api are you calling and where do you get the field that shows you the estimate in seconds?  Is it something you ask for in the `fields` parameter of the request?  And if so, perhaps there's a different field to show you the value as a string?  Just speculating based on the docs.